# Are the 彼の and あの in the examples necessary or optional?

Tags: grammar, context

Are the 彼の and あの in the examples necessary or optional?

**Example 1:**

> 彼は彼女と別れた。"彼の"判断は正しいね。

**Example 2:**

> 新しいパソコンを買ったね。"あの"パソコンは画質がいい？

Answer (score 2):

In both examples, possessives cannot be omitted.

First, in both cases your second sentences are not very natural. Some possible alternatives are:

- 1a. (それは)正しい/賢明な判断だね.
- 1b. (彼の判断は)賢明だね.
- 2a. (そのパソコンの/は)画質はいい？

As you can see from 2a, it is sometimes possible to omit possessive phrases. Easier examples:

- スマホが壊れた
- 彼女がパソコンが壊れたと電話してきた
- 年末にPCを買った。性能はいいが、値段は高かった.

The first one means ***my** smartphone*, the second ***her** PC*, and the third ***its** specs/price*.

Another way to look at the examples would be that you can omit the topic when it is clear. That is, *(Speaking of his decision to end the relationship with her), it is wise*; *(As for the PC you bought), is the display good?*, etc.